# how to create and maintain a soap UI automation framework

Tags: soap, frameworks, automation, soapui

I am new to SoapUI and working on my first project. So far I have managed to automate it as far as possible by creating as follows:

1. groovy script for data transfer
2. running test suite using `testrunner.bat`
3. storing the results dynamically using timestamp
4. integrated it with `ant` and `jenkins` for html report generation.

My question here is for every new wsdl I have to create a new test suite copy(insert) the existing groovy script again and then prepare the test data again accordingly and then finally change the xml name in bat and then execute.

Can i have a deeper approach than this on maintaining a reusable structure rather than performing the same steps again. Is there any other approach to call it a proper framework like testing in selenium?

Comment: You can make use of [Event Listeners](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/custom-event-handlers.html) in SoapUI to build your framework. It supports Java & Groovy

Comment: Thanks for the help but im using the free version so i believe Event Listeners are not available :(

Comment: SoapUI Free Version doesn't have option to add listeners. But you can add listeners by extending SoapUI. The sample has been given         [here](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions)